# Checkbox not working. Trying to dynamically add/remove gridlines in flot.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, flot

I'll add the code then I'll explain.

Segment of relevant HTML:

```
<div id='gridButton'>
    <form>
         <input type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" value="showGrid">Show Grid
    </form>
</div>
```

I used two different kinds of ways to test checkboxes and neither of them worked.

Version 1:

```
$('#gridCheck').on('change', function(){
    if(gridToggle = 0) {
        gridToggle = null;
    } else {
        gridToggle = 0;
    }
});
```

Version 2:

```
$('#gridCheck').on('click', function(){    
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      gridToggle = null;
   } else {
      gridToggle = 0;
   }
});
```

Here's what gridToggle is connected to (this is part of the overall options):

```
    xaxis: {min: -10, max: 60, tickLength: gridToggle},
    yaxis: {min: -5, max:40, tickLength: gridToggle}
```

So the problem I'm having is that when the checkbox is clicked it won't change the gridlines. If I manually put them in the code however, they will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few thoughts:

1.) This `if(gridToggle = 0) {` is wrong, I think you mean `if(gridToggle == 0) {`

2.) Input tag is missing element close, should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" value="showGrid" />
```

3.) Lastly (your real problem), you need to redraw the chart after changing the property:

```
$('#gridCheck').on('change', function(){        
    var gridToggle = $(this).is(':checked') ? null : 0; // on or off
    var opts = myPlot.getOptions();
    opts.xaxes[0].tickLength = gridToggle; // modify existing plot options
    opts.yaxes[0].tickLength = gridToggle;
    myPlot.setupGrid(); // re-init grid
    myPlot.draw(); // and redraw
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UDaE/).

Comment: Thank you so much (I feel so stupid for missing the first to mistakes)! There's one problem though, I'm using JUMFlot which allows the user to dynamically change the points and I just realized this most likely due to redrawing the the graph. However, every time it redraws the graph the gridlines return. Do you know if there is any way to fix this?

Comment: It'll also happen if the page is resized.

Comment: @user3758172, which specific plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I have the jumflot library linked. This one: http://jumjum123.github.io/JUMFlot/javascripts/JUMFlot.min.js

Comment: Yes, but which functionality are you using from that library, it provides A LOT of stuff.  Are doing something like this: http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/interacting_edit.html?

Comment: The thing you linked is exactly what I'm using.

Comment: @user3758172, the problem with the JUMFlot example is that he's *recreating* the plot after each change instead of redrawing it.  Since he recreates it he uses the same base options each time and not the updated options storing the grid status.  I've updated his code to fix this limitation here: http://jsfiddle.net/jUrG7/163/

Comment: It seems like redrawing the plot begins to lag after multiple changes. Is there anyway around this (while still maintaining the checkbox?

Comment: @user3758172, my bad, I didn't take my own advice far enough.  I left the example code reusing the same base data, really it should query the data out of the plot object, and update it.  See this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jUrG7/164/

Comment: It keeps lagging for some reason. Could it possibly be because the draw elements just keep getting placed on top of eachother?

Comment: Hmm, with my last change (http://jsfiddle.net/jUrG7/164/) I can't get it to lag anymore.  Are you using a specific browser?  Did you incorporate that last change I made?

Comment: Neither of the codes you wrote seem to lag in jsfiddle. I'm using chrome

Comment: Is you webpage public?  Can you post a link?  If not, you'll probably have to open a new quesiton, with *your* code that'll reproduce the problem.  Or better yet, create a jsFiddle that'll reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56301/discussion-between-user3758172-and-mark).